# Building a specific version of a solution in a TFS Team Build project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2008 TeamBuild set up and I'm building several solutions:

- Solution A
- Solution B
- Solution C

I would like to build solutions A and B with the latest version from the source control, but for the solution C, I would like to build a specific version defined by the TFS label.

Now, I know about the:

- `/p:GetVersion:LmyLabel` argument for the TeamBuild
- `<PropertyGroup><GetVersion>LmyLabel</GetVersion><PropertyGroup>` element in the .proj file

But that applies to the entire build process and all solutions.

I need it just for one of my solutions, ideally in the `SolutionToBuild` element.

Something like this:

```
<SolutionToBuild clude="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/SolutionA.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
<SolutionToBuild clude="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/SolutionB.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
<SolutionToBuild clude="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/SolutionC.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties>GetVersion=LmyLabel</Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using TFS 2010, you can build from a shelveset. This means that the system first gets all the latest version of the files and then unshelves the shelveset.

However not ideal, you could play with this by creating a workspace based on the version you want to build for solution C. Then create shelveset that contains the changed files for solution A and B.

Another option would be to have 3 different build definitions....

Comment: Different build definitions? But, I would need to queue them somehow? I know there are some options for that, but I'm not really sure whether I should go that way. I simplified the solution structure in my questions...

Comment: You can use the "on every checkin" trigger. If you have different folders where your solution is stored, that is possible.